# How does asort work?

Tags: php, arrays, asort

I was having a look over some of my old work and saw that the asort function would have worked perfectly for some of the uses I needed, although I attempted an extremely different and longwinded way.

So my question is exactly, how does asort maintain association when sorting? I thought an array can be sorted by key, or by value, is there a third sorting pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "third  pivot" is the actual location in memory/array.
You will see it clearly when doing a foreach on the following two arrays, which are the same, but have different order:

```
$x1=array('mmm'=>'mmm','bbb'=>'bbb','ccc'=>'ccc');
$x2=array('ccc'=>'ccc','bbb'=>'bbb','mmm'=>'mmm');

foreach($x1 as $k=>$v) echo "{$k} {$v}";
foreach($x2 as $k=>$v) echo "{$k} {$v}";
```

doing the default asort on those two arrays will result in both cases in:

```
$x1=array('bbb'=>'bbb','ccc'=>'ccc','mmm'=>'mmm');
$x2=array('bbb'=>'bbb','ccc'=>'ccc','mmm'=>'mmm');
```

Comment: From what I can see above there's no actual sorting going on, just 2 arrays, how does the actual asort function take place?

Comment: @S1R It sorts the array (keys **and** values together) according to the parameters you defined. The default I believe is a dictionary sort of the value only.

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) :

> asort — Sort an array and maintain
>   index association

So, for example :

- `Asort` will just sort by **value** in ascending way keeping the index=>value association.
- `Arsort` is the same but in desc way.

The manual is pretty clear on [**Array sorting function** here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

### Basic function only sort by key or values but there are options:

- index->value association maintained or not
- Use of a custom function for sorting or not
- Asc or Desc
- case sensitive or not